# Max size of a fat JAR for Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, shadowjar, fatjar

I've build an Apache Flink app and packaged it in a fat JAR with [Gradle Shadow Plugin](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/). The resulting file size is ~114 MiB. When I'm trying to upload it with Flink's web UI it is stuck in "Saving…" phase. And if I use curl to upload it manually the result is "413 Request Entity Too Large":

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Expect:" -i -F "jarfile=@flink-all.jar" http://ec2-18-204-247-166.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/jars/upload

HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
content-length: 0
```

What are the options, then?

UPD: I can see the JAR in `/tmp/flink-web-UUID/flink-web-upload/UUID/flink-all.jar` but it is not recognized by Flink (not visible on UI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it was easy to fix.

First, I've scanned their repo for "Too Large" string and found [this class](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/rest/FlinkHttpObjectAggregator.java). Looks like `SERVER_MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` is responsible for max object size. It is set [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/configuration/RestOptions.java) from the configuration option `rest.server.max-content-length`. The default is 100 MiB.

**TLDR**:

Setting `rest.server.max-content-length` in `flink-conf.yaml` to `209715200` (200 MiB) solved the issue.